# How to remove multiple keys from a Map dynamically

Tags: scala

Say I have a map like this:

```
scala> val a = Map("a"->2, "d" -> 4, "r" -> 5)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 2, d -> 4, r -> 5)
```

I want to remove multiple keys dynamically from this. While I am able to do this:

```
scala> a - ("a","r")
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(d -> 4)
```

But following fails:

```
scala> val keys = ("d","r")
as: (String, String) = (d,r)

scala> a - keys
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String)
 required: String
       a - keys
           ^
```

While I understand this will be some casting issue, but I am not able to figure this simple thing out.

### Edit

I also tried to make `keys` as array, as in earlier example it became a Tuple, but that also fails.

```
scala> val keys = Array("d","r")
as: Array[String] = Array(d, r)

scala> a - keys
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[String]
 required: String
       a - keys
           ^
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove multiple keys from a `Map`, use the [`--` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#--(xs:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[A]):Repr):

```
a -- Set("a", "r")
```

---

The following explains the type mismatch error.

The version of the [`-` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/MapLike.html#-(elem1:A,elem2:A,elems:A*):Repr) on `Map` that you're calling takes three arguments: (1) the key of the first element to remove, (2) the key of the second element to remove, and (3) a varargs representating zero or more remaining elements to remove. (The other version of `-` takes a single key as the argument.)

```
a - ("a", "r")
```

The above code is not passing a tuple to the `-` method; it's passing two `String` arguments to the `-` method. In other words, the above is equivalent to:

```
a.-("a", "r")
```

However, the code below...

```
val keys = ("d", "r")
a - keys
```

...*is* trying to pass a tuple as an argument to the `-` method. It's equivalent to:

```
a.-(("d", "r"))
```

You get a type mismatch error when you try to pass a tuple to the `-` method, because the `-` method expects one or more `String`s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to remove those keys in scala way dynamically.

Comment: @Saurabh: Updated.

Answer (score 2):

This is nice and concise.

```
scala> a - "a" - "r"
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(d -> 4)
```

If you'd like to compose the list of keys before the removal.

```
val ks = Seq("d","r")
ks.foldLeft(a)(_ - _)  //res2: collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-` operator works on one key at a time according to the `Map` API. If you have a `Array` of keys as you've attempted - You can try a `foldLeft`:

```
val keys = Array("d","r")
scala> keys: Array[String] = Array(d, r)

keys.foldLeft(a)((map, keyToRemove) => map - keyToRemove)
scala> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, immutable `Map`s are provided with the [`removedAll`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#removedAll(keys:scala.collection.IterableOnce[K]):C) method, as an alias of [`--`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#--(keys:scala.collection.IterableOnce[K]):C):

```
// val map = Map("a" -> 2, "d" -> 4, "r" -> 5)
map.removedAll(Set("a", "r"))
// collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map("d" -> 4)
```

> def removedAll(keys: IterableOnce[K]): Map[K, V]